# highstocks responsive styling not working in different devices

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to give my chart responsive styling in three different devices. i created rules iPad pro (max width 2048), iPad (max width 1024) and mobile (max width 480) but its not rendering properly. for iPad pro its rendering iPads styling and for iPad its showing mobile styling.

```
responsive: {
            rules: [

                { 
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth:2048
                        }, 
                        chartOptions: {
                            series: [{
                                dataLabels: {
                                    style: {
                                        fontSize: '25px',
                                        color: 'red'
                                    },

                                }

                            },
                            {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    style: {
                                        fontSize: '15px',
                                    },

                                }

                            }
                        ]


                        }
                },
                {
                    condition: {
                       maxWidth: 1024
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        series: [{
                            dataLabels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '35px',
                                    color: 'green'
                                },

                            }

                        },
                        {
                            dataLabels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '8px',
                                },

                            }

                        }
                    ] 

                }
                }, 


            {
                condition: {
                   maxWidth: 480
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    series: [{
                        dataLabels: {
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '20px',
                            },

                        }

                    },
                    {
                        dataLabels: {
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '8px',
                            },

                        }

                    }
                ] 

            }
            }]
    } `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you noticed that responsive rules like maxWidth and minWidth are applied to a chart width? This is not always equal to screen width.

Highcharts api description of maxWidth:

> The responsive rule applies if the chart width is less than this.

So your code is probably working correctly. Check title on several screen widths in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3stawvum/.

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 2048,
        minWidth: 931
      },
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: '2048 title'
        },
      }
    }, {
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 930,
        minWidth: 401
      },
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: '1024 title'
        },
      }
    }, {
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 400
      },
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: '480 title'
        },
      }
    }]
  }
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.condition.maxWidth

Comment: Hi Chmiel. i changed the rules as you shown in above code. now my chart is working fine. but i still didn't understand the concept of rules conditions with chart width. my chart width is 991 for rule condition maxwidth 2048 and chart width 479 for rule condition maxwidth 1024. can you explain me more detailed

Comment: It is very simple. If your chart has 991px width the rule 931-2048 is applied (at the same time your screen can have 2000 px - but chart width is important here). Notice that I set rule values appropriate only for the chart presented in the example, your chart container can be different (margins etc) so do not use the same values. You have to find values appropriate for your chart.

Comment: hi Chmiel. 0


i'm trying to show dates in x-axis. but it showing like this enter image description here. my series date data is {04/23/2017, 04/30/2017,05/07/2017,05/14/2017,05/21/2017,06/04/2017. my x-axis configuration isxAxis: {
                tickAmount: 5,
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%m/%d/%Y',
                    week: '%m/%d/%Y',
                    month: '%m/%d/%Y',
                 },},  can you help me?

Comment: this is the question i have created. highcharts x-axis irregular date intervels issue

Comment: I've answered you there @sai.